# How can I make this check balanced parenthesis implementation more concise and efficient?

Tags: stack, common-lisp

I'm new to common lisp. I basically translated a procedural implementation of balanced parenthesis using a stack to common lisp. How can I make my implementation more lispy?

```
(defvar str-1 "(this {is [it ()]})")
(defvar str-2 "(this [is {it} )")

(defun matchp (a b)
    "Check if brackets form the correct pair."
    (if (or
     (and (char= a #\{)
          (char= b #\}))

     (and (char= a #\[)
          (char= b #\]))

     (and (char= a #\()
          (char= b #\))))
    t
    nil))

(defun check-paren (str)
    (let ((stack '())
          (temp 0))
    (loop for s across str
      do (if (or
          (char= s #\()
          (char= s #\{)
          (char= s #\[))
         (push s stack))

      do (if (or
          (char= s #\))
          (char= s #\})
          (char= s #\]))
         (progn
             (setf temp (pop stack))
             (if (not (matchp temp s))
             (progn
                 (format t "Mismatch ~%~c ~c" temp s)
                 (return-from check-paren nil))))))
    t))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Concision**

`(if boolean-espression t nil)` can be simply transformed into `boolean-expression`, so your first function can be rewritten as:

```
(defun matchp (a b)
  "Check if brackets form the correct pair."
  (or
   (and (char= a #\{)
        (char= b #\}))
   (and (char= a #\[)
        (char= b #\]))
   (and (char= a #\()
        (char= b #\)))))
```

if you prefer a more concise expression of this, then we could use a `for` loop with two variables that scan in parallel the different open and close brackets, for instance:

```
(defun matchp (a b)
  "Check if brackets form the correct pair."
  (loop for x across "({[" for y across ")}]"
        thereis (and (char= a x) (char= b y))))
```

For the second function, here a few points:

1. instead of using a cascade of `if`, the Lisp languages have a more convenient `cond` expression, so I will rewrite the body by using it;
2. also in this case I will prefer a more concise expression by using the `find` operator on sequences;
3. it is more usual to define the local variables when they are needed, so I will move the definition of `temp` where it is used;
4. finally, I will use the abbreviated form `(let (x) y)` instead of `(let ((x '()) y)`.

So the second function could be something like this:

```
(defun check-paren (str)
  "check if str has balanced brackets"
  (let (stack)
    (loop for s across str
          do (cond ((find s "({[") (push s stack))
                   ((find s ")}]") (let ((temp (pop stack)))
                                     (unless (matchp temp s)
                                       (format t "Mismatch ~%~a ~a~%" temp s)
                                       (return-from check-paren nil))))))))
```

**2. Error handling**

Your function does not check for two different type of errors: too many closed brackets, and too many open brackets. The second case is very simple: we need to check at the end if we have a non-empty stack, otherwise we have an error (too many open brackets).

So we need just perform this check, and use the fact that `format` returns `nil` when it prints something:

```
(defun check-paren (str)
  "check if str has balanced brackets"
  (let (stack)
    (loop for s across str
          do (cond ((find s "({[") (push s stack))
                   ((find s ")}]") (let ((temp (pop stack)))
                                     (unless (matchp temp s)
                                       (format t "Mismatch ~%~a ~a~%" temp s)
                                       (return-from check-paren nil))))))
    (if stack
        (format t "Too many open brackets")
        t)))
```

In the first case, we know that the stack is empty when we try a match. But, if the stack is empty, the value returned by `pop` is `nil`, so `matchp` compare `nil` with a character with `char=`, and this produces an error instead of the `nil` value. A way to simply avoid the errors in this cases is to change the equality operators, for instance by using the `eql` operator, that can compare any kind of values and behaves correctly on characters. This means that we should change the definition of `matchp`:

```
(defun matchp (a b)
  "Check if brackets form the correct pair."
  (loop for x across "({[" for y across ")}]"
        thereis (and (eql a x) (eql b y))))
```

The function is now correct and prints something like "Mismatch NIL )" when it encounters an extra closed bracket.

**3. Efficiency**

Finally, the algorithm used is linear with the length of the string, and since every character of the string must be checked at least once, I think there is no space for further optimization, a part from micro-optimiziations which are not particularly significant.